# Getting Current User Id in AspNet Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So far in Asp.Net I have used this command to get current username

```
var currentUsername = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name)
            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
            : "Anonymous";
```

How should I use this method to get username in AspnetCore ?

Thank you

Comment: Within a controller or external to a controller? If external here is the `IHttpContextAccessor` that can be injected into dependent classes and access the `HttpContext` via that that interface. `var context = accessor.HttpContext`

Answer (score 1):

```
 private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager ;

public LoginController(UserManager<User> userManager){
_userManager=userManager

}
public IActionResult GetUserName()
{
 User user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;
 var userName=user.Username;


}
```